# Magento 2.1.1 when editing catalog product it keeps loading

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm having problem with the store. built with magento 2.1.1, When I edit catalog product in the site, It will not display the required data instead it keeps loading.

Below is the screenshots for your review.

[image]

also this is the error in the console.

[image]

[image]

Thank you,
MazeStricks